# Chunking array in new arrays starting at each word of the array

Tags: php, arrays, chunking

How can I chunk an array in new arrays starting with each word of the original array?
So the first word of each array should be the second word of the previous array.

for example

```
$list(1=>we, 2=>have, 3=>a, 4=>good, 5=>day);
```

Using array_chunk would give as new arrays (we, have), (a, good), (day, and) and so on..
But I want

```
$newList(0=>(we, have), 1=>(have, a), 2=>(a, good), 3=>(good, day));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list) - 2; $i++) {
  $newList[] = array($list[$i], $list[$i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Another way:**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nBZabu)

```
<?php        
foreach ($list as $key => $word) {
    if ($key < count($list) - 1) $newlist[$key][]   = $word;
    if ($key > 0)                $newlist[$key-1][] = $word;
}
?>
```